# Comparing strings of different lengths with compare:options:range: produces wrong result

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, string-comparison

Why does this comparison result in `NO`?

```
BOOL areTheSame = NSOrderedSame == [@"th" compare:@"They" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
```

When I test it on `@"th"` and `@"Th"` it's `YES`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Interesting, how does compare behave with "th" and "they", any difference if you use `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` or not then?

Comment: with options 0 it gives the same results. Odd..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is counter-intuitive, but the `range` argument only applies to the *receiver*. The length of the other string (the argument to `compare:`) isn't range-limited. Your call reduces `@"th"` to the range {0,2}, which produces `@"th"` (i.e., this has no effect), and then compares it to `@"They"`.

You will see that this:

```
NSComparisonResult comp = [@"They" compare:@"th" 
                                   options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch 
                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
BOOL areTheSame = comp == NSOrderedSame;
```

produces the result you expect, because it cuts the receiver (`@"They"`) down (to `@"Th"`) and then does the comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, this is design flaw IMO.